# Basic Inventory Setup with Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, inventory-management

So I'm a Novice to access and need help finishing my Inventory Database.

Currently I have the Following Tables and the field in them:
(Table: Fields, first field is primary key)

> Items: Item#, Item Desc, Item Spec Reorder Level, Qty to Reorder, Qty on Hand
>
> Materials_Used: ID(just an Autonumber field), Project, Item#, Amount
>
> Projects: Project
>
> Purchase_Orders: PONum, Received Date
>
> Receiving_Amount: ID(again autonumber), Item#, Amount, PONum

I'm having issues in 2 area's:

1. Tying in PONum with Items Receiving_Amount: Currently I have a `Purchase_Orders` form which asks the user to input the `date` and `POnum` and a sub form of the Receiving amount in datasheet form. Thing is after I enter a `date` and `PONum`, and move down to entering the Items received I get and Enter Parameter Value box Purchase_Orders.ID and Purchase_Orders.PONumber
   ------ This issues is solved thanks to Wayne!
2. Having the Qty on Hand for the Items table to automatically update once an item is Received through the PO form (adding to it) and Materials Used form (Subtracting)

[Database Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avrAZ.jpg)

Comment: Either your table & field definitions above are incorrect, or you have a typo in your parameter value. You show table 'Purchase_Orders' and some fields, but then have a colon (:) after Receiving_Amount. Is there a field named 'ID' in Purchase_Orders? As for updating, I suggest something like a button click to force some vba code to run to update QTY and Materials Used.

Comment: The Purchase_Orders table above was incorrect, i just edited to reflect it. There isn't a a field named ID for Purchase_Orders, just `PONum`, and `Received Date`. And for updating I was thinking about that but not so sure how to write the code for it, I know it would require to pass that value over to the proper row under the Items table

Comment: Your 'Issue 1' is due to wrong field name in the link or query between main and subform... there is no 'ID' field... Without seeing your full syntax maybe you meant to use PONum?  As for 'Issue 2', what is your subform used for? Does the user type in the qty received for each item in the PO? If so, I can provide some vba code to update the associated tables.

Comment: I just fixed my 1st issued. I ended up recreating the table with a different name along with new forms and what do you know its working... Its keeping track of the Items with the proper PO it was received under. Now i just need help updating the Qty on hand.

Comment: Yes Wayne, you got the idea I'm going for, the subform is there so the user can input the items that were received under that particular PO. So basically once the items are entered, i would like it to add to the `qty on hand` under the items table

Comment: Is this a multi-user database application where there *may* be more than one user updating PO information at the same time?

Comment: Yes, there is a high chance for that to occur, espically since multipal users may be imputing data in the materials_used form while someone might be using the Purchase_Orders  form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will be working in a multi-user update environment, you will need to make sure there are no conflicts with other users. The safest approach is to use a TRANSACTION.

Next, you need to decide how and when to make the updates to your two tables. Let's go with 'Option 1' which is to have a button the user clicks when they are finished. You would need to call the following subroutine when they click the button. You should also keep track if the user made any changes to the subform, but forgot to click the 'Save' button.

Then I strongly suggest keeping track of the changes you have made. For example, user enters qty of 5, saves changes. Tomorrow, looks at the data, sees the 5 and wants to change it to 6... that will corrupt the true inventory. One method to prevent is to have a 'flag' for the PO line items indicating they have been processed and preventing updates again.

The following code is just a sample... I coded what I think should be the input and output recordsets, but you will need to insure the correct input rows are selected to be processed and then select the output row(s) for the tables.

Look for the comments with ## in them.... fix the code to use YOUR control names.

Let me know if you need more of an explanation.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'   BeginTrans, CommitTrans, Rollback Methods Example
'   After the BeginTrans method starts a transaction that isolates all the changes made,
'   the CommitTrans method saves the changes.
'   Notice that you can use the Rollback method to undo changes that you saved using
'   the Update method. Furthermore, the main transaction is nested within another transaction
'   that automatically rolls back any changes made by the user during this example.

'   One or more table pages remain locked while the user decides whether or not to accept the changes.
'   For this reason, make sure you only execute the transaction on some event - don't allow a user
'   to be interactive, else he may go to lunch and may lock pages someone else needs!

'   Add to: Receiving_Amount: ID(again autonumber), Item#, Amount, PONum
'   Subtract from: Materials_Used: ID(just an Autonumber field), Project, Item#, Amount

Sub BeginTransX_Update_Inventory()
    On Error GoTo Error_trap

    Dim wrkDefault      As DAO.Workspace
    Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
    Dim tblInput        As DAO.recordSet
    Dim tblItems        As DAO.recordSet
    'Dim tblMaterials    As DAO.recordSet

    ' Get default Workspace.
    Set wrkDefault = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    ' ## Change the following line to use the name of the form control that has your PONum
    Set tblInput = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from MaterialsRec where PONum = " & Me.txtPONum & ";")            '<<< This will be the source of your changes. Can use a query to filter exact rows.

    ' Start transaction.
    wrkDefault.BeginTrans

    Do While Not tblInput.EOF

        Set tblItems = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from [Items] where [Item#] = " & tblInput![item] & ";")    ' <<< This will be where the updates are applied.

        ' Increase Qty on Hand
        tblItems.Edit
        tblItems![Qty on Hand] = tblItems![Qty on Hand] + tblInput!Amount
        tblItems.Update

        '## Add a text field named 'ProcStatus' to table MaterialsRec, or delete the following update ... your choice...
        tblInput.Edit
        tblInput!ProcStatus = "updated"
        tblInput.Update

        tblInput.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' You can remove the following code if desired...
    ' Ask if the user wants to commit to all the changes made above.
    If MsgBox("Save changes?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        wrkDefault.CommitTrans
    Else
        wrkDefault.Rollback
    End If

    tblInput.Close
    tblItems.Close
    'tblMaterials.Close
    Set tblItems = Nothing
    'Set tblMaterials = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Set wrkDefault = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_trap:
    wrkDefault.Rollback
    MsgBox "An error was encountered, but all changes were rolled back." & vbCrLf & _
            "Err: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
            "Desc: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah i am going to need more of an explanation, it looks like i have to create 3 queries correct? The 1st to select what is causing the change, but the next 2 queries i cant make out its supposed to do

Comment: Please respond to each question: (1) I assume your subform is bound to a recordset of line items for a PO? (2) Users can update QTY in one or more line items? (3) You need to update two other tables to add & subtract qty? (4) How is table Projects related to your PO's? I see no keys to match on? (5) Your form has keys for: PONum, ReceivedDate, Item#, and AMT (qty?). In my sample, the 'Input Query' would select line items for the PO you are working on. Without knowing how to retrieve rows from 'Materials Used', I am stuck..

Comment: 1: Yes, for each PO numbered entered, there can be multiple items. So in the Purchased_order table, you can see all the items amounts of thoses items that are associated with that PO

Comment: 2. Yes,    3. The Receiving_Amounts table will be adding to the specific item on the Items table and the Materials_used will be subtracting from the same table.    4. Projects tables isn't related to the PO's, its purpose will be so  generate a report off a query to how much of each material is being used on a particular project.     5. For the Materials_used I'm using the Item# to relate it to the items table.   I would start a chat with you so i can send you a link to my Access DB but im to llow ranked

Comment: Your explanation for #1 can't be right. Your table 'Purchase_Orders' has no line items. Do you really mean the line items are in RELATED table 'Receiving_Amount' (that is the ONLY other table that has a PO # that will link back to the PO table). Then for #3, you want to update 'Materials_Used', but there is no relationship that I can understand. Please explain.

Comment: 1. Yes, that's i mean, sorry for not explaining it better.  3. Basically, user would input that they used some sort of item and the amount of that item for a specific project. so would like its that what ever item was used its subtracted from `qty on hand` on the items, materials_used relates to the items table by the items# with a 1:many

Comment: I've added an image of the Relationships for my database if that helps. Take note that Purchase_Orders is PONum and Receiving_Amount: is MaterialsRec. When i was fixing the 1st issue i had to give them different names but its the same setup.

Comment: Is there a way to just create a vba code under after update to subtract/add on the proper item line? This would work for testing purposes, and allow me to learn more about access to get it properly setup

Comment: I just updated the answer with code that should work. Call it from a 'Save Changes' button click event. Note you must change the code where you see ## to use the name of your form control. Sounds like you have TWO DIFFERENT forms - the one we have discussed to add inventory from a PO, and a second (unknown to me) that will decrease inventory. This same code can be converted to work with either, or you can clone it and change the table and field names.